# Application object recycling

Tags: asp.net

I have a question about application object recycling.

I do not have any access to the server configuration that i'm using (uni. server), for my project.

Every time that i'm logging to the url, an application object is created. After 20 mins if i reload it again, it appears that the object is re-constructed.

is there a way without having access to the serve iis configuration to elongate this time?

the thing is, that its loading a big index to this object, and it takes time. I want to reduce the number of times constructing the object.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your Session or AppDomain may be idling out or the App pool is recycling.  Both can be configured but you may want to leverage a service layer instead of hosting your object in the ASP side.